# What size should xhdpi launch icons be?

Tags: android

I've created a \res\drawable-xhdpi resource folder to prepare for the hi-res devices, but the developer.android.com site doesn't provide guidelines for the icon sizes for this resoulution. What should I use as the the size of a xhdpi icon?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`mdpi` means ~160dpi, `xhdpi` means ~320dpi.

So, as an `mdpi` icon is 48x48px --> `xhdpi` icon is 96x96px

(I give up, upvote as you like)

Comment: Hackbod has confirmed this. It is 2x the mdpi size. This is clearly missing in the documentation.

Comment: xxhdpi is 144px x 144px (useful info to anyone landing here)

Comment: Android xxhdpi icon = 76 mm , but not all devices are exactly accurate to the density bucket.

xxhdpi = 480 dpi -> 189 dpcm   hence 144 px -> 76mm

And iPhone icons are 89 mm

Retina Iphone 5 = 326 dpi -> 128 dpcm  hence 114 px -> 89mm

Answer (score 32):

follow this ratio 2:3:4:6:8 ratio for mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi:xxhdpi:xxxhdpi

I usually create my assets at the highest level I'm supporting and start downsizing them, making any pixel level hand crafted adjustments as I see the need.

Comment: yeah .. just design for xhdpi, then start resizing downwards for best output.  or simply use Android Asset Studio.  But it gives very limited choices, in which case you wanna go custom.  Then this figure will help you :)

Comment: It's easier to design for xhdpi*3, better scaling ratio ;)

Comment: agreed. however, best designers in the industry tend to rebuild the icons for each size instead of just scaling because pixels are lost when you scale down. they rebuild them.

Answer (score 5):

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)
```

For more information about designing icons, see the Icon Design Guidelines, which includes size information for various bitmap drawables, such as launcher icons, menu icons, status bar icons, tab icons, and more.

Comment: you have a mistake : 144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density

Answer (score 4):

You should see the official documentation for [providing alternate resources for multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources).
According to it, mdpi to xhdpi ratio is 1:2.

Answer (score 2):

From tables [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets) you can easily calculate all standard sizes for `xdpi` resources.

Answer (score 1):

This calculator will help you in finding out which dimensions are needed:

http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/

It works 2 ways (from DPI to PX and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

The rule 3:4:6:8 interpret like this:

4 = MDPI

If MDPI equals X px, then

LDPI = MDPI x 0.75
HDPI = MDPI * 1.5
XHDPI = MDPI * 2

Answer (score 1):

now xxhdpi phones coming,
144x144px in drawable-nodpi folder will suit for every phones